# python ftp retrieve only the last file base on filematch

Tags: python, xml, ftp

Im using python script with FTP connection
Below are the files in my FTP server

testing_01.xml
testing_02.xml
testing_03.xml(this is the latest file)

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('FTP IP')  # open FTP connection to MSM
ftp.login(user = 'username',passwd = 'password')
ftp.dir()
directory ="/temp/" #directory where file should downloaded
filematch = 'testing_*.xml' # a file match to be downloaded
ftp.cwd(directory)
for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch): # Loop - looking for matching files
    fhandle = open(filename, 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)
    fhandle.close()
```

script above will get all files from ftp

My aim is just to get the latest file "testing_03.xml"

Answer (score 1):

[`ftp.nlst()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst) will return a list of file names. So it would give `['testing_01.xml', 'testing_02.xml', 'testing_03.xml']`.
The last item on any list has index `-1`. So to always get the last file, do:

```
file_list = ftp.nlst(filematch)
file_i_want = file_list[-1]
```

or just

```
filename = ftp.nlst(filematch)[-1]
fhandle = ... # the rest of what you have in your for loop, but not as a loop
```